# Looping through all the properties of object php

Tags: php

How can I loop through all the properties of object?. Right now I have to write a new code line to print each property of object

```
echo $obj->name;
echo $obj->age;
```

Can I loop through all the properties of an object using foreach loop or any loop?

Something like this

```
foreach ($obj as $property => $value)
```

Comment: Go head with `foreach` loop you are doing right

Comment: Use a `foreach` (with `=>` not `->`) to iterate through the object **public** properties. You can also make your class [Traversable](http://php.net/Traversable) if you want another behaviour.

Comment: @netcoder: thanks but that was a typo only

Comment: as netcoder said: only public properties will be accessible

Answer (score 177, accepted):

If this is just for debugging output, you can use the following to see all the types and values as well.

```
var_dump($obj);
```

If you want more control over the output you can use this:

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value\n";
}
```

Comment: "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" could well be a resulting error if the object is not an array.

Comment: print_r($obj); can also help. Prints given object's fields recursively.

Answer (score 14):

For testing purposes I use the following:

```
//return assoc array when called from outside the class it will only contain public properties and values 
var_dump(get_object_vars($obj));
```

Comment: If the class of `$obj` is written/controlled by once own, there is also `__debugInfo()` magic method to control what `var_dump()` shows - very handy! Otherwise this answer reduces verbosity, which can also be useful in a step debugger session for E_TOO_MUCH_INFORMATION.

Answer (score 9):

Before you run the `$obj` through a `foreach` loop you have to convert it to an `array` (see: [*cast to array*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5970283/367456)) if you're looking for properties regardless of visibility.

Example with HTML output (PHP 8.1):

```
foreach ((array)$obj as $key => $val) {
    printf(
        "%s: %s<br>\n", 
        htmlspecialchars("$key"), 
        htmlspecialchars("$val"),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, you need to list the variables of an object and not for debugging purposes. The right way to do it is using `get_object_vars($obj)`. It returns an array that has all the visible class variables and their value. You can then loop through them in a foreach-loop. If used within the object itself, simply do `get_object_vars($this)`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `get_object_vars` is better than applying a `foreach` directly to the object since your code will be also compliant with PHPStan which requires that `foreach` is applied only to iterables (see https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/1060).

Thus, the best choice is go like this:

```
foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to express the object property.

```
foreach ($obj as $key=>$value) {
    echo "$key => $obj[$key]\n";
}
```

Comment: This only works if the object implements `\ArrayAccess` or is an `array`, otherwise the following is thrown: `FATAL ERROR Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type SomeType as array`

Comment: You already have the value so just do `echo "$key => $value\n";`

Answer (score 0):

David's answer is solid as long as either: a) you only need access to public attributes, or b) you are working with the stdClass object. If you have defined private or protected attributes in a class and want to display all attributes, simply add an instance method that iterates the properties:

```
class MyClass {

  public $public_attr1;
  private $private_attr2;
  protected $protected_attr3;

  function iterateAttributes() {
    foreach ($this as $attr=>$value) {
      echo "$attr: $value <br/>";
    }
  }

}
```