# foreach on all object properties

Tags: php, loops

How does one perform a foreach over all the fields of a class, either from within that class or from without? For instance, given the following class:

```
class Foo
{
    public $a;
    public $b;
    private $c;
    private $d;

    public function __construct($params)
    {
        foreach($params as $k=>$v){
            $this->$k = $v;
        }
    }

    public function showAll()
    {
        $output = array();
        foreach (this as $k=>$v) {    // How to refer to all the class properties?
            $output[$k] = $v;
        }
        return $output;
    }

}
```

How might the `foreach()` in the `showAll()` method refer to the `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, and `$d` properties?

For that matter, can one get all the public properties from outside the class?

```
$params = array();
$foo = new Foo($params);

foreach ($foo->allProperties as $f=>$v) {    // how to do this?
    echo "{$f}: {$v}\n";
}
```

Comment: `showAll()` returns all the properties if you fix the typo with `$this` (missing dollar sign). The question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Your class does not have any static properties, so technically the class has no values. Do you mean the object properties? This will work with reflection.

Comment: Thank you Wolfgang, I did mean object properties. That would include static members should any exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Reflection class: [Class Reflectionclass Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) ( PHP 5 )

```
<?php
class Foo {
   public    $foo  = 1;
   protected $bar  = 2;
   private   $baz  = 3;
}

$foo = new Foo();

$reflect = new ReflectionClass($foo);
$props   = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC | ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED);

foreach ($props as $prop) {
   print $prop->getName() . "\n";
}

var_dump($props);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you Alireza. I was inclined to accept one of the `get_object_vars` answers, but I see that you've really addressed the core of the issue with Reflection.

Comment: So you were looking for the most complicated solution? ;)

Answer (score 6):

As of PHP4 you can use [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) to iterate over public properties of an object.

```
foreach (get_object_vars($foo) as $f => $v) {
    echo "{$f}: {$v}\n";
}
```

As of PHP5 [you can](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php) iterate directly over the object:

```
foreach ($foo as $f => $v) {
    echo "{$f}: {$v}\n";
}
```

Comment: And how is that different over `foreach` [directly on the object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)?

Comment: @Jon, `get_object_vars` is compatible with PHP4 as well. I've included it as well. Thanks.

Comment: Ι don't see a mention of PHP4 anywhere in the question. Additionally, we are nearing *9 years* since the release of PHP5.

Comment: I should probably also mention that the code given above *is not valid PHP4*.

Comment: PHP4 has no visibility specifiers. And it doesn't recognize the `__construct` name as special, although this last one does not produce a compiler error.

Comment: @Jon, oh yeah, the code of the author is not PHP4, I just wanted to mention that get_object_vars is valid also for PHP4. For future visitors.

Comment: Allow me to remain sceptical about that.

Comment: "As of PHP5 you can iterate directly over the object:" - I couldn't do that in my setup (php 7.2 (yes old version of php, legacy app, but above v5 that it would supposed to work). Casting to array worked fine though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5970283/227926

Answer (score 2):

probably you are looking for [get_object_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

```
$params = array();
$foo = new Foo($params);

foreach (get_object_vars($foo) as $f=>$v) {    // how to do this?
echo "{$f}: {$v}\n";
}
```

you can also use simple object for iteration as of php5. It will also iterate through all public properties

```
$foo = new Foo($params);

foreach($class as $key => $value) {
print "$key => $value\n";
}
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: Is there something wrong with `foreach` [directly on the object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get all properties and their values, including the private ones, from outside the object, and without relying on undocumented behaviour or implementation details, is [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php):

```
$ref=new ReflectionObject($object);
foreach ($ref->getProperties() as $prop)
{
    $prop->setAccessible(true);
    $name=$prop->getName();
    $value=$prop->getValue($object);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_class_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php) — Get the default properties of the class
You can do like below:

```
<?php
class myclass {
    var $var1; // this has no default value...
    var $var2 = "xyz";
    var $var3 = 100;
    private $var4; // PHP 5    
    // constructor
    function myclass() {
        // change some properties
        $this->var1 = "foo";
        $this->var2 = "bar";
        return true;
    }
}
$my_class = new myclass();
$class_vars = get_class_vars(get_class($my_class));
foreach ($class_vars as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name : $value\n";
}
?>
```

For more info just check [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php)

Answer (score 0):

While you can iterate over public object attributes using [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php), having to do this might be a bad design and a reason to think about your implementation again. The thing you want to do with the attributes of the object most probably belong into the class/object itself, programmatically.