# How to make a array inside array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this two array. I want to make a array inside an array like this. How can I achieve that. Code posted below. This is the image I am sending inside fileToUpload.
The array I have

```
Array
(
    [fileToUpload] => Array
        (
            [name] => KERINOX COFFEE.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /opt/lampp/temp/phpuk5Uyo
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 2440617
        )

)
```

The array I want

```
Array
(
    [fileToUpload] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => KERINOX COFFEE.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /opt/lampp/temp/php0LlvE2
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2502103
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want it like that? What is the purpose?

Comment: I need to upload the image using curl. So i need to match this array.

Comment: Why though? Does the server you're sending it to accept a different data format? Are you intending to just upload the array, or the actual file as well. What you're asking for seems a bit strange so i just wanted to clarify that it's definitely what you actually need, and not based on some prior misunderstanding.

Comment: When I am trying to upload image using form the second array is generating. But when I trying to upload it through cURL the first array is generating and the image is not inserted in the server. But through the form it is inserting into the server.

Comment: Related: [How to cast variable to array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5970270/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `array_map` for this, to wrap each element into another array:

```
$data['fileToUpload'] = array_map(
  function($item) {
    return [$item];
  },
  $data['fileToUpload']
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough to build a new array:

```php
$array = [
    'fileToUpload' => [
        'name' => 'KERINOX COFFEE.jpg',
        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'tmp_name' => '/opt/lampp/temp/phpuk5Uyo',
        'error' => 0,
        'size' => 2440617
    ]
];
$newArray = ['fileToUpload' => []];

foreach ($array['fileToUpload'] as $key => $value)
    $newArray['fileToUpload'][$key][] = $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $myArray = [];
 $myArray['fileToUpload']['name'] = array("file name");
 $myArray['fileToUpload']['type'] = array("file type");
 $myArray['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] = array("temporary name");
 $myArray['fileToUpload']['error'] = array("error");
 $myArray['fileToUpload']['size'] = array("file size");

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($myArray);
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhJ45.png)