# How can I put JSON to MySQL with PHP loop?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have JSON like this (from nested sorting)

```
[
 {"id":13},{"id":14},
 {"id":15,
   "children":[
          {"id":16},{"id":17},{"id":18}
    ]
 },
 {"id":19},{"id":20},
 {"id":21,
      "children":[
          {"id":22}
      ]
 }
]
```

how I PHP loop to put this JSON in MySQL

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As with any valid `JSON` format string, you can use PHP's built-in `json_decode` to convert it into a parsable object and then loop through those parameters. In this case, from the `JSON` string you've given (which seems to be an array)

```
$array = json_decode($string);
foreach ($array as $val) {
    //The object $val will be:
    "id":13
}
```

If it's nested, you would do another foreach loop and detect for the property that needs to be looped. For example you could do this in a variety of ways (check for the `"children"` property, loop through the `$val` properties and check if it is an `array`, if it is then loop through that). Inside this foreach loop iteration, you can insert it, or do execute whatever statement you need to get it inside MySQL

Your question  is pretty vague on the format and way you want it inserted. I'd suggest showing some code you've tried so other people can help you and know what direction you're going in. (that's probably the reason for the downvote, not mine by the way)

[Looping through all the properties of object php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976624/looping-through-all-the-properties-of-object-php)

Comment: I think he wants to store his data inside mysql. Not get access to it.

Comment: I edited my answer to show him that he can access the data and use it iteration in `foreach` to insert it (overhead costs, but I'm not sure what he wants to do with it). Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

just put your valid json inside json_decode and assign it to a php array as below

```
//$php_arr = json_decode('YOUR_JSON');
$php_arr = json_decode('[{"id":13},{"id":14},{"id":15,"children":[{"id":16},{"id":17},{"id":18}]},{"id":19},{"id":20},{"id":21,"children":[{"id":22}]}]');

/*comment the following 3 lines when done*/
echo "<pre>";
print_r($php_arr);
echo "</pre>";
/*comment the above 3 lines when done*/
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 13
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 14
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 15
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 16
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 17
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 18
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 19
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 20
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 21
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 22
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now as you have PHP array do what ever you want like

```
 foreach($php_arr as $arr){
    if(!isset($arr['children'])){
        $q = "insert into tbl(id) values('".$arr['id']."')";
    }else{
        //your logic
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `json_decode` function to decode JSON data. Then use `foreach` loop to manipulate data.

Try example

```
$str = '
    [{"id":13},{"id":14},{"id":15,"children":[{"id":16},{"id":17},{"id":18}]},{"id":19},{"id":20},{"id":21,"children":[{"id":22}]}]
';

$json = json_decode($str);

//var_dump($json);
foreach ($json as $item)
{
    //The object $val will be:
    echo $item->id."<br />";
    //You INSERT query is here
    //echo "INSERT INTO table (field) VALUE ($item->id)";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO table (field) VALUE ($val->id)");
}
```