# PHP function : Return a object value if it's set

Tags: php

I'm trying to output a value of on object, but the value might not exist for some object records.  How do I return the value without raising error *"Undefined property: stdClass"*?

For example, I have an object:

```
$obj = '[{"id":111,"value1":1,"value2":2},{"id":111,"value1":1}]';
```

`value2` does not exist for the second element in the array, and I want to write a function to process each object in the array. Example:

```
function add($obj){
   $sum = 0;
   foreach($obj as $o){
      $sum += $o->value1;          

       if(isset($o->value2)){
          $sum += $o->value2;
       }
   }
   return $sum;
}
```

The `if` part is what I want to improve.  There might be dozens of other values that don't exist for some object. I don't want to write `if(isset($o->valueN))` every time.

Is there any other easier ways to code this to avoid the undefined property error?

Comment: Try iterating through `$o` maybe? Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976624/looping-through-all-the-properties-of-object-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: In php7 you can use the Null Coalescing Operator,

```
$sum += $o->value2 ?? 0;
```

Option 2: If you can create specific classes for the sub-items, then you can use magic method __get() so you only need to write `isset` once.

Option 3: Accept it? My code is littered with isset()s as it's a good reminder that something may or may not be set, but you know it and are handling it.

Answer (score 1):

This will make sure you only add the occurances you want and only if they exist in the array.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); 

$obj = '[{"id":111,"value1":1,"value2":2},{"id":111,"value1":1}]';
$obj_array = json_decode($obj);

$required_occ = ['value1', 'value2'];

$sum = 0;

foreach ( $obj_array as $obj ) {
    foreach ( $required_occ as $occ ) {
        if ( isset($obj->$occ) ) {
            $sum += $obj->$occ;
        }
    }
}

echo $sum;
```

Result

```
4
```

Or to cut it down a bit, If youare using PHP7 and using the Null Coalescing Operator

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); 

$obj = '[{"id":111,"value1":1,"value2":2},{"id":111,"value1":1}]';
$obj_array = json_decode($obj);

$required_occ = ['value1', 'value2'];
$sum = 0;
foreach ( $obj_array as $obj ) {
    foreach ( $required_occ as $occ ) {
        $sum += $obj->{$occ} ?? 0;
    }
}

echo $sum;
```

Result

```
4
```