# Automatically Populate stdClass from MySQL

Tags: php

I'm using `stdClass` to create a class and I'd like to add all column data to it automatically.  Currently, I'm doing the following from within a function...

```
function get_course_info($course_id){
   $course = new stdClass;

   //Add everything from the courses table to the "$course" class
   $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE course_id = ?",array($course_id));
   $results = $query->first();

   $course->type = $results->type;
   $course->category = $results->category;
   $course->name = $results->name;
   etc.......
```

This is working fine, but if I someday add a new column to the courses table (let's say "description"), I'd like that info. to automatically be added to my `stdClass` without having to go back and manually add it in as a new line in this function.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976624/looping-through-all-the-properties-of-object-php)

Comment: Why don't you just use the object returned from the query? I.e. `$course = $query->first();`

Comment: `SELECT *` is not something you want to use. You \want\ to update your function when your data changes because they should never be arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, "foreaching" through the object returned from MySQL was the way to go (credit to Mischa).

```
    //Add everything from the courses table to the "$course" class
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE course_id = ?",array($course_id));
    $results = $query->first();

    foreach($results as $column => $value){
        $course->$column = $value;          
    }
```

Hope it helps someone.